# Train Model fails because 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, training-data

I am training a classifier over tweets for sentiment analysis purposes.

The code is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Trainded Dataset Sentiment.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df.head(5)
```

[image]

```
#TWEET
X = df[['SentimentText']].loc[2:50000]
#SENTIMENT LABEL
y = df[['Sentiment']].loc[2:50000]

#Apply Normalizer function over the tweets
X['Normalized Text'] = X.SentimentText.apply(text_normalization_sentiment)
X = X['Normalized Text']
```

After normalization, the dataframe looks like:

[image]

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =
sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#Classifier
vec = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5, max_df=0.95, sublinear_tf=True,
                      use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,2))
svm_clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=0.1)
vec_clf = Pipeline([('vectorizer', vec), ('pac', svm_clf)])
vec_clf.fit(X_train, y_train) #Problem
joblib.dump(vec_clf, 'svmClassifier.pk1', compress=3)
```

It fails with the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

[image]

```
Full Traceback:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-33-4264de810c2b> in <module>()
      4 svm_clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=0.1)
      5 vec_clf = Pipeline([('vectorizer', vec), ('pac', svm_clf)])
----> 6 vec_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
      7 joblib.dump(vec_clf, 'svmClassifier.pk1', compress=3)

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    255             This estimator
    256         """
--> 257         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    258         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    259             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in
_fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    220                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    221                     cloned_transformer, None, Xt, y,
--> 222                     **fit_params_steps[name])
    223                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    224                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    360 
    361     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 362         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    363 
    364     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in
_fit_transform_one(transformer, weight, X, y, **fit_params)
    587                        **fit_params):
    588     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 589         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    590     else:
    591         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)    1379             Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.    1380         """
-> 1381         X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)    1382         self._tfidf.fit(X)  1383         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
    867 
    868         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
--> 869                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
    870 
    871         if self.binary:

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    790         for doc in raw_documents:
    791             feature_counter = {}
--> 792             for feature in analyze(doc):
    793                 try:
    794                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(doc)
    264 
    265             return lambda doc: self._word_ngrams(
--> 266                 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
    267 
    268         else:

C:\Users\Monviso\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <lambda>(x)
    230 
    231         if self.lowercase:
--> 232             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    233         else:
    234             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: I assume is error is in `X['Normalized Text'] = X.SentimentText.apply(text_normalization_sentiment)` line, but hard to understand without full traceback

Comment: what is text_normalization_sentiment doing?

Comment: It tokenizes the tweets, and normalizes the text

Comment: I added a preview of the normalized text

Comment: can you post the actual code for the normalization function please?

Comment: vec_clf.fit(X_train, y_train) #Problem

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The TFIDF Vectorizer should expect an array of strings. So if you pass him an array of arrays of tokenz, it crashes.

Comment: How can I pass the tokens then?

Comment: Give him the normalized string but not tokenized. It will tokenize it.

Comment: I'm tokenizing them taking into account specific features. Is it not possible to preserve my tokens somehow?

Comment: Yes, see docu. Parameter "tokenizer". http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: you don't need to keep them tokenized. join them back together after you normalize so that there is one string in each row.

Comment: like cameron wrote, just rejoin the tokens with whitespaces after the normalization (if you really need to tokenize them for normalization in the first place). vectorizer wants an array [ "this is a test" , "this is another test"]

Comment: vec_clf.fit(X_train, y_train) #Problem --> I had the same problem, just change it to array of strings, not array of arrays of string - like this: `vec_clf.fit([' '.join(arr) for arr in x_train], [' '.join(arr) for arr in y_train])`

Answer (score 6):

add this code `.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))` after X_train and y_train and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from
http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/28/TfidfVectorizer/

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def dummy(doc):
    return doc

tfidf = CountVectorizer(
    tokenizer=dummy,
    preprocessor=dummy,
)  

docs = [
    ['hello', 'world', '.'],
    ['hello', 'world'],
    ['again', 'hello', 'world']
]

tfidf.fit(docs)
tfidf.get_feature_names()
# ['.', 'again', 'hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 2):

**Apply**

```
X = df.text.astype(str)
```

I had the similar problem but instead of extracting values using `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]`, I simply used

```
X = df.text
y = df.target
```

which converts the dataframe column to `Series` having `list` as each row and tokenized items as `objects` in each row. The series looked similar to what Alex had:

```
print(X)
```

[image: Directly converted series]

So, only `.astype(str)` worked for me.

Result:

[image: Series after applying .astype(str)]